# Whats wrong with this code? I'm trying for user input "z" to exit the program

Tags: java

I want user input "z" to exit a program which obtains three inputs. If user enters z the program should terminate.

It runs but z returns an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
```

The code:

```
while (input.hasNextLine())
{
    if ("z".equals(input))
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Should it not be `if("z".equals(input.nextLine()))`?

Comment: You're comparing a `String` to a `Scanner`.

Comment: @Gendarme Yes, Thank you!